# Error 'Cannot find name 'particles'' when displaying particles using JSON file in Pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js, particles

I'm trying to display particles on a canvas using a JSON file generated by the https://pixijs.io/pixi-particles-editor/. I'm following the example provided on this website: https://www.pixijselementals.com/#particles

Here's my code:

```
import { Application, ParticleContainer, Texture } from 'pixi.js';
import { Emitter } from 'pixi-particles';
import * as particleSettings from './emitter.json';

const app = new Application({
    view: document.getElementById('pixi-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement,
    resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    autoDensity: true,
    backgroundColor: 0x6495ed,
    width: 640,
    height: 480
});

const particleContainer = new ParticleContainer();
app.stage.addChild(particleContainer);

const emitter = new particles.Emitter(particleContainer, Texture.from("particleTexture.png"), particleSettings);
emitter.autoUpdate = true;
emitter.updateSpawnPos(200, 100);
emitter.emit = true;
```

I'm getting an error "Cannot find name 'particles'." during compilation. I have installed the latest versions of pixi.js and pixi-particles.

Could you please help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it? I would appreciate any guidance or insights. Thank you!